# C-ares распарсить DNS запрос, готовые решения

Tags: c, dns

Поиск наработок или врапперов к библиотеке [c-ares](https://c-ares.haxx.se/docs.html) позволяющий распарсить входящий DNS запрос полученный в 'сыром виде'.
По сколько именно эта библиотека уже входит в проект, то городить огород из чего либо ещё не хотелось бы. В API в явном виде ничего подходящего для этих целей не обнаружено. Есть конечно заголовок [ares_dns.h](https://github.com/winlibs/c-ares/blob/master/ares_dns.h), там есть макросы для работы с сырым пакетом. Так вот собственно вопрос, есть ли какие сторонние наработки, врапперы или ещё какие нибудь готовые решения для этой библиотеки для разбора 'сырых DNS requests'.

Буду признателен за возможный код, Гугл на эту тему немногословен, а изобретать велосипед нет время и желания. Заранее спасибо за внимание к вопросу.

Comment: DNS протокол, если не ошибаюсь, достаточно простой, почитайте спецификацию. Есть ли готовая реализация... возможно. Прошерстите поисковиком `dnsd c++` и `dns c++`

Comment: Там достаточно подводных камней, чтоб на отладку ушло время, и не маленькое. Сейчас и есть самописное, так вот хочется поменять на 'одно целое'.